# HTTP 500 The Website Cannot display the page

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, sockets

This is the Java Code To receive the Data from C Server using Sockets and store the data in Google Data Store and Deploy the app on Google app Engine.

```
package pack.exp;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CToJavaToCloudServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
static List<String> obj1; 

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
{
        Socket s = new Socket("10.9.11.55", 6870);
    InputStream stream = s.getInputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[13];
    int read;
    String can_Id= null;


    while((read = stream.read(data)) != -1)
    {
        can_Id= String.format("%02X%02X%02X%02X", data[0], data[1], data[2],    
            data[3]);

    String can_Data= String.format("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", 
            data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7], data[8], data[9], data[10], data[11]);

    obj1= new ArrayList<String>();
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(0, 2));
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(3, 5));
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(6, 8));
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(9, 11));
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(12, 14));
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(15, 17));
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(18, 20));
    obj1.add(can_Data.substring(21, 23));
    }
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
           IOException 
{
    Key k1 = KeyFactory.createKey("C","0C F0 0400"); 

    String statusEEC1= obj1.get(0);
    String driversDemandEnginePercentTorque= obj1.get(1);
    String actualEnginePercentTorque= obj1.get(2);
    String engineSpeed= obj1.get(3) + obj1.get(4);
    String sourceAddressOfControllingDeviceForEngineControl= obj1.get(5);
    String engineStarterMode= obj1.get(6);
    String engineDemandPercentTorque= obj1.get(7); 

    Entity can1 = new Entity(k1);

    can1.setProperty("Status EEC", statusEEC1);     

            can1.setProperty("Drivers Demand Engine Percent Torque", 
            driversDemandEnginePercentTorque); 

            can1.setProperty("Actual Engine Percent Torque", 
            actualEnginePercentTorque);

            can1.setProperty("Engine Speed", engineSpeed);

            can1.setProperty("Source Address Of Controlling Device For Engine Control", 
            sourceAddressOfControllingDeviceForEngineControl);

            can1.setProperty("Engine Starter Mode", engineStarterMode);

            can1.setProperty("Engine Demand Percent Torque", 
            engineDemandPercntTorque);


    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(can1);

    Entity can11 = null;

    try 
    {
        can11= datastore.get(k1);
    }

    catch (EntityNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String statusEEC11= (String) can11.getProperty("Status EEC");

            String driversDemandEnginePercentTorque1= (String) 
            can11.getProperty("Drivers Demand Engine Percent Torque");

            String actualEnginePercentTorque1= (String) can11.getProperty("Actual 
            Engine Percent Torque");

            String engineSpeed1= (String) can11.getProperty("Engine Speed");

            String sourceAddressOfControllingDeviceForEngineControl1= (String)  
            can11.getProperty("Source Address Of Controlling Device For Engine  
            Control");
    String engineStarterMode1= (String) can11.getProperty("Engine Starter 
            Mode");
    String engineDemandPercentTorque1= (String) can11.getProperty("Engine 
            Demand Percent Torque");


    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Can id 0C F0 0400------>");
    resp.getWriter().println("");
    resp.getWriter().println("Status EEC--- " + statusEEC11);  
    resp.getWriter().println("Drivers Demand Engine Percent Torque---" +  
            driversDemandEnginePercentTorque1);  
    resp.getWriter().println("Actual Engine Percent Torque---" + 
            actualEnginePercentTorque1);  
    resp.getWriter().println("Engine Speed---" + engineSpeed);  
    resp.getWriter().println("Source Address Of Controlling Device For Engine 
            Control---" + sourceAddressOfControllingDeviceForEngineControl1);  
    resp.getWriter().println("Engine Starter Mode---" + engineStarterMode1); 
    resp.getWriter().println("Engine Demand Percent Torque---" +                 
            engineDemandPercentTorque1); 
    resp.getWriter().println("");
    resp.getWriter().println("");
    resp.getWriter().println("");
    resp.getWriter().println("");
   }
}
```

On deploying the app to google cloud engine I am getting the error. 
The website cannot display the page
 HTTP 500
Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

Can anybody help me out with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `javax.servlet` and `javax.servlet.http` packages provide interfaces and classes for writing servlets. All servlets must implement the Servlet interface, which defines lifecycle methods. When implementing a generic service, you can use or extend the GenericServlet class provided with the Java Servlet API. The HttpServlet class provides methods, such as `doGet` and `doPost`, for handling HTTP-specific services.

Since you are implementing `HttpServlet` interface, you have to implement  `doGet` and/or `doPost`.

Servlet init methods allows a servlet to perform one-time initialization prior to servicing requests. One common mistake when implementing init method is in this form:

So your `main` method is not called at all. Move the code from main into `init`.  Another problem with your code is that you are opening a socket expecting data. This should be done in  `doGet` and/or `doPost` methods since they are responsible for receiving data.

Comment: @  user987339
I have replaced main method with public void init() 
and my Socket code is in init() method only, I am getting the data from the server continuously but after deploying I am getting the same error and also the data is not going in the datastore viewer table of GAE

Comment: Servlets within containers are not meant to listen on any other port. Actually you'll have to write a servlet for doing what you was doing in main method. But it wan't getting data through a socket, but through doGet method (ie. servlet container is responsible for oppening socket etc.)

Comment: @ user987339
Do I have to put the socket and InputStream code in init() of one servlet and then call the other servlet's doGet method which consists of the code to put the data on the datastore.

Comment: Something like this. But you don't put there socket code, since GAE is responsible for this. you can get InputStream from HttpServletRequest req with getInputStream method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45630/discussion-between-shanx-and-user987339)